# Login function : Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a new project using React, Express and MySQL and my app keep crashing whenever I use the login route. The registration route works fine though.

My frontend:

```
function Signin() {
  const [userNameLog, setNameLog] = useState('');
  const [userPasswordLog, setPasswordLog] = useState('');

  const login = () => {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/auth/signin', {
      prenom: userNameLog,
      password: userPasswordLog,
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  };

  return (
    <SignUpWrapper>
      <SignUpTitle>Connectez-vous !</SignUpTitle>
      <input
        type='text'
        placeholder='Prenom'
        onChange={(e) => {
          setNameLog(e.target.value);
        }}
        required
      ></input>
      <input
        type='password'
        placeholder='Mot de passe'
        onChange={(e) => {
          setPasswordLog(e.target.value);
        }}
        required
      ></input>
      <StyledButton onClick={login}>Se connecter</StyledButton>
    </SignUpWrapper>
  );
}

export default Signin;
```

My backend:

```
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.prenom;
    const password = req.body.password;

    res.json({ message: 'Votre requête pour se connecter a bien été reçue !' })

    db.query(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE prenom = ? AND password = ?",
        [username, password],
        (err, result) => {
            if(err){
                //Permet d'envoyer une réponse au front en cas d'erreur
                res.send({err: error});
            } else {
                if (result) {
                    res.send(result);
                } else{
                    res.send({message : "Wrong combination of name and password"});
                }
            }     
        }
    )
}
```

I've been googling it since 2hours but I still don't get where does my mistake come from

Comment: i think res.json({ message: 'Votre requête pour se connecter a bien été reçue !' })
 would have sent response headers to UI, when you call res.send it tries to send again but you can only respond once to the calling client so express throwing error

Comment: Like @santhosh suggested. Try to remove or comment the `res.json({ message: 'Votre requête pour se connecter a bien été reçue !' })` line in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

As the other users points on the comments, the error is caused by tried to send another "batch" of headers to the client.
The first line `res.json(...)` is sending the headers already.
You must call just one res.json per request.

Of course you can have one res.json per branch in your code, but be sure only one is called per request in the route.

[Here is the error code of the official NodeJS Docs](https://nodejs.org/dist./v8.14.1/docs/api/errors.html#ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT)